# Left Join performance in DBT on GCP Bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery, dbt

I'm trying to build a reusable model which will be used in multiple data pipelines constructed on DBT running on GCP Bigquery. I basically want to get a column value from two disjointed tables.

I created a DBT model UNION-ing those two tables

data for tbl1 -
col1#####col2#######col3
ABC1 ###### A1 ######## T1
ABC2 ###### A2 ######## T2
ABC3 ###### A3 ######## T3

data for tbl2 -
col1 ###### col2
A1 ######## T11
A2 ######## T21
A3 ######## T31

data for fact table -
col1 ####### col2
ABC1 ####### XX
ABC2 ####### YY
XYZ  ####### A1
DEF  ####### A3

For the data in fact table, row 1 & 2 must match with the tbl1 data and row 3 & 4 must match with the tbl2 data.

```
with tbl1 as 
(select col1,col2,col3
from project1.dataset1.table1 ) 

,tbl2 as 
(select col2, col3
from project1.dataset1.table2 )

,tbl1_tbl2 as 
(
select col3, 
case when col1 is not null then col1
when col2 is not null then col2 end as single_col
from (
select col3,
case when flg = 'tbl1' then col1 end as col1,
case when flg = 'tbl2' then col2 end as col2
from
(select 'tbl2' as flg, null as col1 ,col3, col2 from tbl2
union all 
select 'tbl1' as flg, col1,col3,col2 from tbl1
)
) 
)
```

This is how the model will be used in data pipeline - fact joined with the model. But the challenge here is that when either of the JOIN columns' value is matching with the UNION-ed tables then I need the data. But the OR condition in the LEFT JOIN.....ON fails in Bigquery. When I say fails is that BQ goes on for a ride. I'm not sure if I'm approaching it correctly or if there's a better way to solve this issue. Please help!

```
select col3
from project1.dataset1.fact_table fact
left join 
tbl1_tbl2 tbl
on 
tbl.single_col = fact.col1
or tbl.single_col = fact.col2 --This is where BQ fails
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on “BQ goes on for a ride”? Is an error returned?

Comment: Hi Josh, 
“BQ goes on for a ride” -> no BQ doesn't throw any error but goes on and on in the execution plan - 
It shows 1 day 1hr as slot time consumed in Execution Details section and keeps on steadily increasing the time. But shows bytes processed as very less in 100s of MBs only.

Answer (score 0):

Using an `or` in a join predicate causes terrible performance in many different warehouses. You can replace this with two left joins, and `coalesce` the values from the two joined tables:

```sql
select coalesce(a.col3, b.col3) as col3
from project1.dataset1.fact_table fact
left join tbl1_tbl2 a
    on a.single_col = fact.col1
left join tbl1_tbl2 b
    on b.single_col = fact.col2
```